# Android OptionsMenu Hide First Item

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, options-menu, android-optionsmenu

folks.

Here's the problem.  Let's say I have three items on my menu.  I want the first one to be invisible (like transparent) but at the same time consumes space. And the second and third to be display normally.

Thanks

EDITED:

I have three items on the menu.  I have menu arranged vertically, so like this:

```
Menu:    
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

Now, I want the first item to be invisible (still there consuming space, but is not visible to the eye).  So it will look like this now:

```
Menu:

Item2
Item3
```

You see, it's still there but not any part of it is visible. (background color set to transparent, no text, etc.)

Comment: can you not just change the text to `""` aka blank

Comment: Can you provide anymore context with what you are trying to achieve? If you set the text to "" then your still going to be able to click that option. Hard to advise you because we don't know why you are doing something so abstract.

Comment: Have you tried `menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false)`?

Comment: @nistv4n, tried it, not my expected output though

Comment: Okay. But Why do you want it like this. Reasoning? Why do you want a "margin". I think D Yao's answer would do the job fine, not sure why it must be clear background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think menu items only have two options - setVisible(false) which removes it (doesn't take up space), or setEnabled(false), which grays out the option but it's still visible.

If you really want to have it take up space, perhaps you can try a combination of setTitle("") with setEnabled(false) on the menuitem which you want to make hidden but still consume space.

e.g.,

```
menu.getItem(0).setTitle("");
menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
```

This way, the item will be there, but it will be disabled so that clicking it will not trigger its action.

Comment: any idea on how can I make the first menu transparent so it would look like invisible?

Comment: as I said, set title to the empty string, and setenabled to false

Comment: yeah, it's still there, with its background color. so it's not really invisible.

Comment: @mai it makes no sense what you are trying to achvieve. If you want an option to be completely inivisible. Why not remove it?.. +1 for a good answer DYao.

Comment: I need it to consumes space. So I like have a margin.

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do anymore mai. If you want to remove it to not be there, just call menu.remove(id) on the menu item id.

Comment: so then why is it a concern that the background color is there, you're not making any sense. maybe post your menu and main layouts along with a clearer description of what it is you're hoping to achieve, otherwise we'll accomplish nothing here.

Comment: do you want it to never be visible? or only visible in certain situations? It isn't possible to change the background of an item. You still are not making any sense. What background are you talking about? we need to see xml layouts and code to understand you.

Comment: How about making a menu not clickable?

Comment: to do this, use menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);